# Firebase didn't send OTP to mobile -- Android Studio firebase phone authentication error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I add SHA1 & SHA-256 to firebase console & following dependencies in build.gradle file.

Actually the problem is that my mobile didn't open Browser to CAPTCHA

Dependecies

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
 implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
```

ERROR

```
E/FirebaseAuth: [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400

E/zzf: Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash.]- calling backend without app verification
```

Comment: It says from the exception that probably your set up is wrong

Comment: I received OTP successfully before I share my project with my teammate in GitHub, but after I share my project with my team member with GitHub, I'm getting this errors.

Comment: Any conflicts in the repo?

Comment: No, didn't get any conflicts

Comment: Firebase configuration?

Comment: I Configurate my Project with firebase  https://prnt.sc/10nsizs and also I added SHA 1 & SHA-256 both in my firebase console

Comment: FirebaseException for onVerificationFailed Method  {  onVerificationFailed : This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details. }

Comment: if you are building apk from other machine make sure firebase console have SHA certificate of that machine too .

Answer (score 1):

Enable Android Device Verification

Use below the link to Enable Android Device Verification.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com